# Specify R for Jupyter Notebook with Anaconda Windows

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I feel pretty comfortable working with R, and I want to get into Python through Anaconda.
Upon trying the Jupyter Notebook and finding it has compatibility with R, I really want to use it.

I'm having problem installing the R packages that don't come in R-essentials; and mainly because I noticed it uses a different R installation than the one I had before.  Not only is this a different R installation, but it also uses a previous version of R.  In my local installation I have updated to 3.2.3 but in the Anaconda environment for Jupyter I got 3.1.

I also found a post to change the `.libPaths` variable to include the packages that I had already installed.  Still, I see this as a potential problem because of the different R versions.

I wanted to know if I can update the R version that's used in Anaconda, or if I can point to the one that's installed locally.

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect this involves a non-R package manager interaction with an OS and you are not providing any of that information. I'll retract my close vote if you clarify the question with needed details.

Comment: From what I understand Anaconda has it's own package manager `conda`.  
I modified the title to mention Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can install IRkernel in the normal R installation and then register the kernel: simply follow the instructions at http://irkernel.github.io/installation/